# How to load a Modal with JQuery (.load) into in it at the same time once button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In this scenario I would like to preserve bandwidth by when a modal opens then it loads the import_audit_table into a Div in the Modal.  Is this possible?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#import_audit_div1').click(function(){
    $('#import_audit_table').load("edit_audits.php?action=import");
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Modal Opener" id="import_audit_div1" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#import_audit_div'/>

<div class="modal" id="import_audit_div" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>
                <div id="import_audit_table">
                </div></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <form method = "POST">
                <input type="button" id="yes_delete" value="Yes " name="deleteaudit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </form> 
                </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try it? If so what happened?

Comment: The modal comes up, but not the import_audit_table,

Comment: Note that `<div>` is invalid child of `<h3>`. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to make sure it is succeeding